# What's the best way to bind key/value pair to an asp label

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a situation which come in front of me very often but I don't have any solution to it right now.
Suppose I have a key/value pair like this

```
UserID | UserName
-----------------
1      | Yogi
2      | Mike
```

I want to bind this data to an asp label control,
Right now what I do is, I bind UserID to the tooltip of the label & UserName to the text of the label, It works fine but drawback is that when user hovers the label it shows UserID as a tooltip to the user which is obvious.
I want to find some better way to do this job, please help me to get a better approach here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simple use any other custom name attribute to save and read your UserID.

eg

```
Control.Attributes["data-uid"] = UserID.ToString();
```

Comment: This is the perfect approach!

Comment: @Sirwani Thank you, have one minus, the UID is visible to the html source code. At the same time is plus because he can used by javasript.

Comment: @Aristos.. But if he has to avoid it on page source he has to bind it in listbox is guess..

Comment: This is a good approach but, this will add an attribute to my Label's UI, & it will not validate on w3c validation,
But still it's a better solution than tooltip

Comment: @yogi yes maybe is not validate on w3c but is used a lot to store information's like that in some cases, and supported by all browsers.

Comment: HTML5 permits you to create custom attributes as long as they are prefixed with "data-". They are called custom data attributes and are covered in the spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes -- so "data-uid" is an attribute you could use that would pass W3C validation.

Answer (score 4):

**For ASP.Net**

Create a custom attribute like

```
mylabel.Attributes["attributename"] = value;
```

**For WinForms/WPF**

Give it in its `Tag` property. I use that property for these kind of purposes.

Provide Username in Label and when it is label is hovered over, extract the tag (array or list) and display in tooltip.

```
mylabel.Tag = value;
```

Comment: `Tag` property is not found in `asp:Label` control, It's in Windows `Label` control

Answer (score 0):

I would have used UserId as ID of label, and for better readability I would have used

```
Label.ID = "lblUser_" + UserId.toString();
```